# How to configure MvcMiniProfiler to use Entity Framework with a Domain layout

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, mvc-mini-profiler

I would use MVCMiniProfiler with Entity Framework, I saw that I could configure like this to get the object context :

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDBEntities"].ConnectionString;
var entityConnStr = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString);
var connection = new SqlConnection(entityConnStr.ProviderConnectionString);
var profiledConnection = ProfiledDbConnection.Get(connection, MiniProfiler.Current);
var objectContext = ObjectContextUtils.CreateObjectContext<MyModel>(profiledConnection);
```

The problem is that I have a my domain model in another project of the solution and I can't use this method. I also use dependency injection for my repository:

```
   public MyController(IEntities repository)
    {
        _repository = repository;
    }
```

I am looking for a way to configure MvcMiniProfiler.